jQuery ajax call returns different things on different servers
I have the same front end and back end code running on two different servers (each frontend calls the associated back end, no CORS issues involved).
One one server I make a jQuery 3.5.1 $.ajax call to the backend and I get the proper HTML string back.  On the other server I get just an object showing a successful call with a 200 response code, no data.  It seems like a server config problem but I can't figure out what.
This is a .NET 4.7.1 API.  I've hardcoded the API endpoint to return a static string so I don't think it has anything to do with backend logic.
The .NET endpoint looks like this:
<Route("news/GetVarsDue/{lastMonthAct}/{acctType}")>
<HttpGet>
Public Function GetVarsDue(lastMonthAct As String, acctType As string) As HttpResponseMessage
    Dim response = New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    response.Content = New StringContent("<label>helloBrad</label>", Encoding.UTF8, "text/html")
    Return response
End Function

and the front end looks like this:
function queryVarStatus() {
    var url = "api/news/GetVarsDue/12-1-2015/CA";
    console.log("FrontPageNewsPanel: news url " + url);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET"
    }).done(GetVarsDueSuccess).fail(GetVarsDueError);
    return true;
}

function GetVarsDueSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    console.log("Current jQuery version: " + $.fn.jquery);

    if (data === null) {
        console.log("FrontPageNewsPanel: news success data is nothing");
        return true;
    }

    if (data.length === 0) {
        console.log("FrontPageNewsPanel: news success data is empty");
        return true;
    }

    console.log("FrontPageNewsPanel: building success news grid");
    console.log(data);

    //do important stuff here

    return true;
}

The response I get on the good server is this:

The response I get from the naughty server is this:

This feels like it's something with the server config but I cannot figure out what.
Both servers are the same:

On @kiko suggestion below I hit the URLs directly from a browser.  The good server returned just the string "helloBrad" but the naughty server gave this error.

Examining the received response on the good server shows this.

Bad server gives this

I am now hitting just the endpoint from a browser (not allowed to use Postman).  I hard coded the endpoint to return a 202 with a reason phrase.  The good server returns the 202 and reason phrase.  The naughty server returns a 200, not the 202, and blank reason phrase.
I get the same results if I hit the endpoint from the server itself.

Just out of curiosity, what happens if you don't use JQuery AJAX to get the URL, but just enter the URL in a browser? Does one server return the correct HTML and the other doesn't? If that's the case then you don't need to look at JQuery at all. Otherwise, if both server return the correct HTML, and you could even swap them with the same result, you know it has something to do with JQuery on the naughty front end server.

I had a similar problem in the past. No data with http 200. But after I set correct response type at server, datatype in ajax call, etc; tried again and the http 200 turned into 301 (cors) revealing what the actual cause was. It's like cors error was being conceiled.

I tried @KIKOSoftware suggestion above and the good server returns the "helloBrad" string while the naughty server says "XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it".   In the endpoint I'm clearly setting the return type as text/html.  What would make a server interpret this as XML?  Maybe a missing handler?

If you see this: "XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it", message, I would have a look at the source code of that page. It could be, just like in this example, your server actually generated an error message. Looking at your edit of the question, this seems indeed the case. A "Status code" of 500 means your server encountered an error. Ah, it even says: "An error has occurred"! Time to look at the server logs to find out what that error is.

Your "naughty" server isn't returning a "bad response", it's actually failing completely - it's not your code that's being returned.   Could be anything.

I tested this and you are correct.  I changed the return type to a 202 with no content.  The good server returned the 202 but the naughty server returned 200.  Adding content makes  it break like before.

Adding a Reason Phrase to the 202 and the good server returns the phrase while naughty returns blank.

Hitting the endpoint from the server itself gives the same results as from a browser on a different machine on the network
